# How to display the information of peak hour from last 24h data from influxDb

Tags: influxdb

I am working on a project on influxDb where I have a time-series data. Here I have to find the peak hour and display the data during that peak hour.

The task is to

- group the 24hour data to 1hour each and get the mean value.
- Among these mean value I have to find the max value and it's time.
- Using this time we have to display the data for that 1 hour.

I have wrote the query to find the max value and time-period

```
SELECT max(mean) 
FROM (SELECT mean("value") 
    FROM "measurement" 
    WHERE ("floorNo"='1' AND time >= now() - 24h) 
    GROUP BY time(1h))
```

Comment: That should work (aside from the duplicate SELECT word at the beginning of the statement). You can also create an alias in the inner query like `SELECT mean("value")  as mean_value`.

Comment: The query that you have should take care of the first two points. The third one you'd probably have to handle separately, meaning you'd look at the timestamp of the result for the max mean value and then send another query to get the data for corresponding hour.

Comment: @NikolayManolov the above query will return a timestamp and value. Is there a way to filter out the timestamp and pass to to another query to get the data for corresponding hour

Comment: No. That's the problem. For whatever reason you can't "select" the timestamp as a field and do operations with it and so you can't really pass it into another query. Otherwise it would have worked quite nicely.  Perhaps you could try using Flux. Might be possible there. https://github.com/influxdata/flux